# Unity Camera component error when tried to implement player following camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I am trying to do: have the camera follow the character like Mario

I'm getting this error:

> Assets/Camera_System.cs(22,65): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.GameObject.transform'

Code:

```
void Start () {
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");   
}

void LateUpdate () {
    float x = Mathf.Clamp (player.transform.position.x, xMin, xMax);
    float y = Mathf.Clamp (player.transform.position.y, yMin, yMax);
    GameObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (x, y,GameObject.transform.position.z);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type

```
transform.position
```

or

```
 gameobject.transform.postion
```

lowercase `gameobject` not

```
GameObject.Transform.Position
```

`transform` is not static member of the class `GameObject` and you are trying to access non static member as static

Comment: @SchreyerKarl What this tries to say is that `GameObject` (upper case) is a class name. You want the MonoBehaviour property called `gameObject` (lower case). Hint: if you want the `Transform` component of the same `GameObject` this script is attached to you can also completely omitt the `gameObject` and only use e.g. `var x = transform.position.x;`